# if statement not reporting anything in python

Tags: python

I'm a beginner in python, when I run the script it doesn't say there's an error I need to fix but when it gets to the part of the if statement it doesn't report anything.

```
import random

username = input("What is your name?")
print("Hello",username)
highestValue = input("What do you want your highest value to be?")
highestValue = int(highestValue)
randomNumber = random.randint(0,highestValue)
print(randomNumber)
guessedNumber = input("Take a guess at my secret number")

if guessedNumber == randomNumber:
  print("Congratulations! You guessed my secret number")
```

Comment: Looks like guessedNumber is a string while randomNumber is a number.

Comment: `input` returns a string for `guessedNumber`, and you haven't converted that to an `int`. Even if you guessed the correct number, `16` does not equal `'16'`, so your `if` statement would evaluate to `False`. You might want to add an `else` statement so you can tell that at least *something* is happening when you guess incorrectly.

Comment: Thank you I just used and the type() method and it's stored as a string

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `guessedNumber` is a `str`, as `input()` returns a string.

To solve this, either

**1)**
Cast `randomNumber` to a `str` using `str(randomNumber)`

or

**2)**
Cast `guessedNumber` to an `int` using `int(guessedNumber)`

The first solution is safer, as `int`s can always be casted to a `str`, whereas `str`s can only be cast to an `int` when it contains a number. However, you will need to use the second solution if you want to compare the numbers by checking if one is higher or lower than the other. To prevent errors with the second solution, you can use `if guessedNumber.isnumeric()` before casting it to check that the user inputted a number.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
import random
username = input("What is your name?")
print("Hello",username)
highestValue = input("What do you want your highest value to be?")
highestValue = int(highestValue)
randomNumber = random.randint(0,highestValue)
print(randomNumber)
while True:
    guessedNumber = int(input("Take a guess at my secret number"))
    if guessedNumber == randomNumber:
        print("Congratulations! You guessed my secret number")
        break
```

Output:

```
What is your name? bob
Hello bob
What do you want your highest value to be? 10
2
Take a guess at my secret number 5
Take a guess at my secret number 3
Take a guess at my secret number 4
Take a guess at my secret number 2
Congratulations! You guessed my secret number
```

I added a `while` loop so the program keeps running until the user gets the number right and I had to convert `guessedNumber` to an `int` as `randomNumber` is also an `int`

Comment: I might be mistaken here, but isn't the code you posted the exact same as what the original poster posted?

Comment: oops, I did not copy the right code :) I just edited it include the new code. I guess i just forgot to press ^C

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because when you use input in python, the value is a string by default, and when comparing a string to a number, the result will always be False.

To correct your code, use int(input()):

```
guessedNumber = int(input("Take a guess at my secret number"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Any input in python is str, to make it work, you just need to change input:

```
import random

username = input("What is your name?")
print("Hello",username)
highestValue = input("What do you want your highest value to be?")
highestValue = int(highestValue)
randomNumber = random.randint(0,highestValue)
print(randomNumber)
guessedNumber = int(input("Take a guess at my secret number")) #Make it int value

if guessedNumber == randomNumber:
  print("Congratulations! You guessed my secret number")
```